# Animations/transitions when switching between views iOS8

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm very new to iOS programming and I have two simple `UIView`'s.

.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainPageOutlet;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *secondPageOutlet;
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction)secondPageToMain:(id)sender {
    self.view = [self mainPageOutlet];
}

- (IBAction)mainPageToSecondPage:(id)sender {
    self.view = [self secondPageOutlet];
}
```

How can I use animations or transitions when switching between these two views? Currently they only appear when the button is clicked. Ideally I'd like to have something like push, modal, slide in or up.

Is there a way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why you are using two uiview's, you can use two uiviewcontrollers and then use push methods of uiviewcontrollers.

Comment: Because I'm not sure I know how to :(

Comment: It depends on what you want to show in these two views. If there are large number of child elements you want to show in these views then better go for uiviewcontrollers. If there is a need to show that content in uiviews then we can add transitions on these uiviews.

Comment: Yes, only to show the content. No child elements are involved in those views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code.

```
- (IBAction)secondPageToMain:(id)sender {

   [UIView transitionFromView:[self secondPageOutlet]
                        toView:[self mainPageOutlet]
                      duration:2
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [[self secondPageOutlet] sendSubviewToBack];
                    }];
} 

- (IBAction)mainPageToSecondPage:(id)sender {

    [UIView transitionFromView:[self mainPageOutlet]
                        toView:[self secondPageOutlet]
                      duration:2
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [[self mainPageOutlet] sendSubviewToBack];
                    }];
}
```

And in your viewDidLoad method add following code,

```
    [[self secondPageOutlet] sendSubviewToBack];
```

So initially your second view will be behind your main view and on performing action it will come in front with animation.

Comment: cool, that's what I needed. `[[self secondPageOutlet] sendSubviewToBack];` didn't work for me, so I used `completion:nil` thank you so much :)